# How to update browser version via selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest

Environment: 
 OS: Windows server

I have remote Jenkins environment for python selenium tests running. Is it possible to force update browser version (Chrome, Firefox, etc) using selenium as preconditions before test running? For now I can only check version, but in case of failed version check I need to update browser manualy on Jenkins server. So updating via python selenium will be a big profit.

Answer (score 1):

Why would it be preferable to manage the installed version of the browser with Selenium?

Instead, use the build server's operating system's package manager, e.g., apt for Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install --assume-yes firefox
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems it is a good and easy way. Sorry I didn't say that  I have windows server as Jenkin's environment. Tried to find current solution for windows but nothing got as result. Maybe you know/heard something fo windows?